# Prevent Closing of JDialog from Exit Button

Tags: java, swing

I searched google and stackoverflow quite a bit and they all indicate that using:

```
d.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

will prevent the exit button from closing the dialog, as of now, it is not... Posted below is the relevant code snippet that seems to be having problems:

```
if (gameArea.hitChest()) {
    JDialog d = new JDialog((JFrame) gameArea.getTopLevelAncestor(), "Dialogue", true);
    ChestLoot ch = new ChestLoot(player);
    d.add(ch);
    d.setSize(200, 100);
    d.setVisible(true);
    d.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

    d.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
            System.out.println("Don't Close!");
        }

    });

    System.out.println("Should dispose here");
    TileIcon ches = gameArea.getCurrChest();
    gameArea.removeChest(ches);
}
```

Comment: move the `d.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);` to before the `d.setVisible(true);`. I recommend doing everything on the dialog before setting it visible.

Comment: @Quincunx That fixed it, damn swing logic! Thank you.

Comment: Once you call `setVisible` the dialog is shown. As your dialog is modal, this method call with block until the dialog is closed; hence all your calls after that point are somewhat pointless...

Comment: @DylanLawrence, that is not to be a *damn*. That is actually a perfect logic. When anything is visible, we see it as is, we want it to function as it is visible now. All the definition with which we want to see it, should be given before it appears before us.

Answer (score 2):

Your `JDialog` is a modal dialog, so everything after `setVisible(true)` doesn't affect it. Move relevant code to before `setVisible(true)`:

```
if (gameArea.hitChest()) {
    JDialog d = new JDialog((JFrame) gameArea.getTopLevelAncestor(), "Dialogue", true);
    ChestLoot ch = new ChestLoot(player);
    d.add(ch);
    d.setSize(200, 100);

    d.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

    d.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
            System.out.println("Don't Close!");
        }

    });

    d.setVisible(true); //code pauses here and waits for the dialog to be handled

    System.out.println("Should dispose here");
    TileIcon ches = gameArea.getCurrChest();
    gameArea.removeChest(ches);
}
```

It is a good habit to only set the dialog as visible when you have finished setting all the options, even with non-modal dialogs.

See [`JDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Dialog,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29), it says this:

> dialog blocks user input to other top-level windows when ***shown***

Also mentioned in [An Overview of Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#overview).